# strcat paste second string at beginning of first string

Tags: c, string, strcat

i use `strcat()` to connect two strings like:

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *args[])
    {
       char *str1; // "456"
       char *str2; // "123"

       strcat(str1,str2);
       printf("%s",str1);
    }
```

i get:

```
456123
```

but i need the second string on beginning of first string like:

```
123456
```

how can i do it ?

Comment: You example is not clear. What is `char * str1; // "456"` meant to do? It won't produces the output you show, but run into Undefined Behaviuor, as there is no memory allocated for any characters, but `str1` and `str2` point just somewhere, randomly.

Comment: str1 is a long string, I need to add another string at the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

Do `strcat(str2,str1);`, switch the parameters. But you will get resultant string in `str2`, which you can set to `str1` if you really want to use `str1` further in your program.

However, you need to take care appropriately for memory space available in `str2`.

---

If you want to change `str1` then, do this

```
char *tmp = strdup(str1);

strcpy(str1, str2); //Put str2 or anyother string that you want at the begining
strcat(str1, tmp);  //concatenate previous str1

...
free(tmp); //free the memory
```

Comment: i need to add " " (blank) to beginning of str1

Comment: @Refael, Check updated answer. You can change it to append as many strings possible.

Comment: Ooh, this asumes `str1` referencing enough memory! Which is not clear from you example. `strcat()` is nothing more then a pseudo smart copy function. It's surely no "memory-area-concatenator"! It does **not** append the memory allocated by the call to `strdup()` to the memory referenced by `str1`! Only `realloc()` is able to extend an area of already allocated memory.

Comment: @alk, this assumes that `str1` has enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this with static sized arrays, works for me in my project.

```
void strbeg(char* strReceive, char* strInsert)
{
    int strInsertLength = strlen(strInsert);
    int strReceiveLength = strlen(strReceive);

    for(int i = strReceiveLength; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        strReceive[i + strInsertLength] = strReceive[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < strInsertLength; i++)
    {
        strReceive[i] = strInsert[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim from `man strcat`:

> char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough
>          space for the result.

As the programmer you need to make sure that the pointer `char * dest` references enough valid memory to hold the addtional `char`s that will be copied from where `char* src` points to.

To succesfully prefix `str1` with `str2` declare them as follows:

```
char str2[3 + 1] = "123"; // three for "123" plus 1 for the terminating 0
char str1[2 + 3 + 1] = "46"; // 2 for "46" plus 3 for "123" plus 1 for the terminating zero
```

to actually concatenate the two `char` arrays do so:

```
strcat(str1, str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you segfault on this because you have two non-allocated strings with different sizes, maybe it'll solve the probleme.
I first calculated the size difference to allocate the first string with the bigger size (in which [padding] will be concatenated at the begining). Then added the code of @Rohan.

```
if (len1 < len2) {
    char *tmp = strdup(num1);
    num1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(num1) + diff));
    strcpy(num1, padding);
    strcat(num1, tmp);
    printf("%s\n", num1);
    free(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add a single char :

```
char *add_char_to_beginning(char c, char **str)
{
    char *tmp = strdup(*str);
    *str = (char *) realloc(*str, sizeof(char) * (strlen(*str) + 2));
    *(str[0]) = c;
    strcpy(*str + 1, tmp);
    free(tmp);

    return *str;
}
```